# easyrtc.listen failing - Waterfall not working?

Tags: azure, webrtc, async.js, easyrtc

I'm trying to deploy EasyRTC on Azure platform.

Somehow it looks like its not executing the waterfall funcions (The one that prints for example, "Configuring Http server").

It reachs the debug info "Running func 'onStartup" but the functions on the waterfall are not being triggered, or I cant understand why it is failing inside the functions as all trace info that I'm trying to output its not getting out(thats why I suspect that the functions are not triggered).

I dont really know how to approach to a solution to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated package.json to latest node version(8.9.0) and reinstalled all packages with npm solved this thing.

Hopefully this can help anyone.
Thanks!